# Singular asymptotic limits of mean-convex MCF

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, parabolic-pde, geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces, flows

Let $(M_t \mid t \geq 0)$ be a mean-convex mean curvature flow of hypersurfaces in ambient Riemannian manifold $(N^{n+1},g)$. Brian White proved that this flow (defined 'weakly' as a level set flow for example) essentially either vanishes in finite time, or converges to a stable minimal hypersurface as $t \to \infty$.

In any case, let us assume the latter behavior, namely $M_t \to M_\infty$, where $M_\infty$ is a stable minimal hypersurface. White also proves that $M_\infty$ has 'optimal regularity', in the sense that $\operatorname{dim} \operatorname{sing} M_\infty \leq n - 7$.

> I am looking for an example where $M_\infty$ 'tests' this bound, say where $n = 7$ and $\operatorname{sing} M_\infty$ is non-empty.

Something along the lines of Pitts' starfish example seems promising, but there might also be easier examples. I'd be perfectly happy with a sketched argument.

Comment: If a closed 2-sided singular minimal hypersurface $M$ admits a piecewise smooth strictly mean convex foliation of its neighborhood, then by maximum principle, starting from each leaf of this foliation will provide a mean convex MCF that converges to $M$ itself.  Theorem 1.6 in this paper <https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.00548> provides criterion for such mean convex neighborhood to exist.